# Why can I not read or write session? Throws NullObject Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api

I am making a WebAPI app and am finding that I can not read or write to session. How I would normally do it gives and NullObject Reference Error, ie:

```
Session["Test"] = "Testing"; var testing = Session["Test"].ToString();
```

Would anyone happen to understand why that is for this example?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace DotNetNuke.Modules.ContactsManager
{

    public partial class ServicesController : DnnApiController
    {
       [AllowAnonymous]
       [HttpGet]
       public HttpResponseMessage createRequest(string amount)
       {
          //code omitted     
          HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = "Test";
          //code omitted
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: -1: What happens when you try? "I can not read or write to session" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: So, your actual question is, "Why Session["Test"] null right after I set it?"

Comment: Because the only reason to get a NullReferenceException on dereferencing Session["Test"], is if Session["Test"] is null!

Comment: could you offer some suggestions based on my usage as to why this might be when I am able to use the examples successfully in other areas of my application, namely in a view.ascx.cs

Comment: I have no idea. You haven't posted enough of your code or told us enough context to determine this. Also, when you say "successfully", do you mean that you are able to do the following in all other areas? `Session["Test"] = "Testing"; System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(Session["Test"] != null);`

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you are not adding to the session properly.

Try doing something like `HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Test", "Test");`

Your second statement `var testing = Session["Test"].ToString();` will then retrieve the data as you would expect.

Comment: That sounds like it should work but in my case I get a NullReferenceException just like I did from my original example.

Comment: both the read and write statements in my example produce the same NullReferenceException. The thing about this is I have a view.ascx page and if I use the statements in my original example in the view.ascx.cs they work fine. The issue is using the statements in another class (ServicesController.cs)

Comment: I don't have enough of your code to make a good enough assertion but it seems like it isn't being placed into your session for use elsewhere. E.G. Your view.ascx.cs plays nicely but if you go to view2 or wherever you have yet to add "test", it cannot find it because it does not exist. Could I perhaps get a taste of the procedure you use to reproduce this?

Comment: **both statements cause this?** Nice of you to tell us. I'm voting to close this question. I'd love it if you would start a new question, on your _actual problem_, which is just that the write statement doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I found my answers, it was all about inheritance. My explanation might not be worded very well as i am still learning as I go but here it is.

The class I am working in is already inheriting an ApiController Class and in my DotNetNuke project it seems that things like Session are contained in the "{NameSpace}ModuleBase" class. So implementing an IDisposable

```
    using(myPorjectModuleBase base = new myProjectModuleBase())
{
 var testing = Session["Test"].ToString();
}
```

I can then access session.

This is probably specific for module development on the DotnetNuke platform from version 6.2 and up.

Thanks to everyone for your assistance.

Comment: Could you include the code for the myProjectModuleBase class?  It doesn't really answer the question without it.

Comment: I has same issue and have not solution to solve this. Please post the code in detail to explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code this is sample example in C#

```
public static string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry I did not not realize this answer was provided.. I have found my solution. it is quite specific to my environment I think.